# How to find ("closed-form") solutions to lasso-type problems?

Tags: optimization, lasso, regularization

Say, we have $f(\beta) = \sum_{i=1}^n(y_i - \sum_{k=1}^p Z_{ik}^2\beta_p^2)^2 +\lambda\sum_{k=1}^p|\beta_p| $, where $\beta \in R^p$.

How do you find a closed form solution to argmin $f(\beta)$?

I know how to find a closed form solution for $g(\beta) = \sum_{i=1}^n(y_i - \sum_{k=1}^p Z_{ik}\beta_p)^2 +\lambda\sum_{k=1}^p|\beta_p| $, where $\beta \in R^p$, as it's the lasso solution using coordinate descent method with sub-derivatives for the $L_1$ penalty and the derivative of the loss function (i.e., shown here: https://www.coursera.org/lecture/ml-regression/deriving-the-lasso-coordinate-descent-update-6OLyn).

But finding the argmin of $f(\beta)$ seems more tricky... Is there a general way to do this if we have different loss functions?

Thank you for any insights!

Comment: In what sense can a "coordinate descent method" be considered a "closed form solution"??  What would constitute something that is not "closed form"?

Comment: Sorry, I mean an efficient method based on solving something involving closed-form

Comment: What do you perceive as being the difference between $f$ and $g$?  As far as I can tell they do not differ in any essential way; the sole difference is the replacement of an $L_1$ penalty in $g$ by an $L_{1/2}$ penalty in $f.$

Comment: Thanks for your response. I thought about it being just an $L_{1/2}$ penalty as well. But how would you solve it in a similar way? Use the sub-gradient of $\sqrt{\beta_i}$?

Comment: That's what one would hope.  (I haven't studied penalties of a type where the derivatives become infinite.)